# Combining data from 3 separate Spreadsheets in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, vlookup

I'm trying to combine data from 3 separate spreadsheets:

-All three sheets have a common column called "Tag" which has ID numbers
-Sheet 1 contains the most info and will be used as the sheet where everything will be merged into.
-Sheet 2 has certain dates which i would like to move to sheet 1 but i want the info matched up with the correct ID numbers and hence end up in the same row in sheet 1 as the data in sheet 1 with the same ID number
-Sheet 3 also has certain info i would like to move to sheet 1 and i also want the info presented the same way as the info from sheet 2.

How should I go about doing this? I'm not as good with vlookup and pivot tables and im unsure what can help me best and how to do it.

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the data on each sheet organized the same as far as the number of columns and the ordering of those columns goes?

Comment: The only thing similar between all three sheets is that their first column is called "Tag" which houses the ID numbers. the columns that come after are all different...  for example sheet 1's columns are TAG-Shop Name-Shopaddress; then sheet 2's columns are TAG-Date requested-Date Shopped-Estimate received; then sheet 3's columns are TAG-Dispo requested-DispoReceived-Ship Date

Comment: Just use Vlookup - assuming your tag is always your first column. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vlookup/info Are you familiar with autofill?

Comment: Im not that familiar with vlookup but definitely willing to learn. And no, not familiar with autofill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of Vlookup:

[image: Example1]

You can simply use this formula to populate all the other data for each tag on your master worksheet.

Autofill is a way of populating formulas and values into other cells - by dragging your initial formula into those other cells. You should read about it as it is an essential part of nearly any use of excel.

http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s2p2.html